# Using a Custom format with binding source?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a number of classes which have a string property to hold the [IBAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number).

For display purposes, I would like to display the value with a space after every 4 characters, for example:

```
'GB29 NWBK 6016 1331 9268 19'
```

Is it possible to write a class that implements `ICustomFormatter` and then specify this new custom format for the textbox data bindings?

Or would handling the `BindingComplete` event of the `BindingSource` be a better way?

Comment: How about writing an extension method on string may be that returns formatted string? so the method will be like ToIBAN() on string

Comment: @Dheeraj An extension is easy to write but I would need to handle the Parse and Format events, instead of setting something like `{0:I}` where `I` is the format string

Comment: What about using a `MaskedTextBox` for display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to associate custom [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) with the class properties of that type.

For instance:

**Formatter:**

```
public static class IBAN
{
    public static string Format(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            (i != 0 && (i % 4) == 0 ? sb.Append(' ') : sb).Append(value[i]);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Converter:**

```
public class IBANTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return IBAN.Format(value as string);
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

**Sample data class with property:**

```
public class MyObject
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IBANTypeConverter))]
    public string IBAN { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample data binding:**

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var data = new MyObject { IBAN = "GB29NWBK60161331926819" };
        var form = new Form();
        var tbIBAN = new TextBox { Parent = form, Left = 8, Top = 8, Width = form.ClientSize.Width - 16, Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right };
        tbIBAN.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "IBAN", true);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to "unformat" the string when the textbox gets the focus?

Comment: I'm afraid no, except if you use a special control supporting that. Data binding supports just format and parse.